# Java: IllegalAccessException

Tags: java, exception

There is an error while compiling this. Whereas there is no error when I try to throw a NullPointerException.
Could anyone please help me on this one?
Thanks.

```
class ThrowsDemo {
    static void throwOne(){
        System.out.println("Inside throwOne.");
        throw new IllegalAccessException("demo");
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            throwOne();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "There is an error": Show the error! Now, others have already given the correct answer, but please post *complete* questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Andreas I added the errors I get in Eclipse with that code is that better?

Comment: @toskv LOL, nope! ;-) I can paste that into Eclipse too, but I was trying to teach `iame` to follow the *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable* principle of Stack Overflow, in this case, the *Complete* part is lacking.

Comment: @Andreas hehe, makes sense. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because IllegalAccessException is a checked exception you have to add **throws IllegalAccessException** to the throwOne() to inform any calling methods that they need to handle it.

```
static void throwOne() throws IllegalAccessException {
```

Comment: np. If you want to throw an exception that is not checked it needs to inherit from RuntimeException (as NullPointerException does).

Comment: btw, if the answer is satisfactory please mark it as the correct one. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because IllegalAccessException is chceked exception you must declare that your method can throws this exception. Just add to throwOne method definition 'throws IllegalAccesException'